# parse array of json object into a particular format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have parsed the array of json object into a particular format but i need the "type" property value of object to to be dynamic based on condition.

```
    input >>
    [
      {
        "accident_description": "bike accident",
        "reported_by": "john",

      },
       {
        "accident_description": "car accident",
        "reported_by": "sam",

      }
    ]

    output >>
    "fields": [
        {
          "title": "accident_description",
          "values": "bike accident"
          "type": "generic",

        },
        {
          "title": "reported_by",
          "values": "john",
          "type": "generic",

        },
        {
          "title": "accident_description",
          "values": "car accident"
          "type": "generic",

        },
        {
          "title": "reported_by",
          "values": "sam",
          "type": "generic",

        },
      ]
```

I have tried this and it is working fine

```
const arr = [ { "accident_description": "bike accident", "reported_by": "john", }, { "accident_description": "car accident", "reported_by": "sam", } ];
 let res = arr.flatMap(x => (Object.entries(x).map(([k,v]) => ({title:k,values:v,type:"generic"}))));
   console.log(res);
```

but here type is fixed ,i need "type" value to dynmaic based on the condition given below.

```
if(title=='accident_description')
type:generic
else
type:custom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a ternary operator. Instead of

```
{title:k,values:v,type:"generic"}
```

do

```
{title:k,values:v,type:(title=='accident_description') ? 'generic' : 'custom'}
```

In cases where the logic is more complicated than a simple conditional, bear in mind that the arrow function which you've used in `map` can have arbitrary code in the body, so you can do any calculations you need and `return` the final `type` value you want.

Comment: thank you for the answer i tried your solution and it is working fine but i also need to compare that actually with another title like title=='value1'||title=='value2' and it is not working.. acn you please help me with like writing a function there for type attribute to get values based on condition  . I have to compare title with 2 values.

Comment: the code is more or less exactly the same in that case: `type:(title=='value1' || title=='value2') ? 'generic' : 'custom'`